# Angular pushing into array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an angular calendar and have some events like this :

```
$scope.events = [
        //{title: 'test event',start: moment()},
        {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
        {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
        {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
        {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
        {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ];
```

Is it possible to dynamically push into this so for example a button that could keep adding another event? i cant think of the syntax to push the object into array

Answer (score 3):

This is just a javascript array, so you use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
$scope.events.push({
    title:'foo'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

```
$scope.events=[];
var event={title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)};
$scope.events.push(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have .push() method in Array through it you can push elements to array.

Example:

```
$scope.events = [
        //{title: 'test event',start: moment()},
        {title: 'Long Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2)},
        {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),allDay: false},
        {id: 999,title: 'Repeating Event',start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0),allDay: false},
        {title: 'Birthday Party',start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),allDay: false},
        {title: 'Click for Google',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://google.com/'}
    ];


$scope.handleClick = function() {
    $scope.events.push({title: 'Click for XYZ',start: new Date(y, m, 28),end: new Date(y, m, 29),url: 'http://someurl'});   
}
```

Similarly to remove the elements from the array, we have pop() method provided.

Answer (score 0):

The `push` is as simple as 1-2-3. Please refer to the code snippet for pushing a new object into an existing AngularJS object below:

```
$scope.events.push(newData);
```

You can refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/75yt033j/) for full code.